# Is it appropriate for me to ask questions about using Mozilla Thunderbird on Windows 7 here?

Tags: discussion

I'm apparently in danger of being blocked from asking anymore questions if I ask any others without checking they are OK so I felt it best to ask whether a question about Mozilla Thunderbird, namely about setting the folders incoming items are sent to, would be appropriate for this website.

Comment: It should be fine, yes

Comment: Just remember that the *content* of a question is just as important as the *subject* of the question. If your question about this subject trails off into a subjective question, expect downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Mozila Thunderbird on Windows 7 definitely falls into that category, as long as the question is "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".